# Need to use counter variable in scala.html and display using @for(i <- list){@(a++)}

Tags: playframework

```
play-framework-twirl-template
```

[1. I have multiple questions in variable list.
    2. Need to declare variable outside for loop and use as counter variable in for loop.
    like @var count=0;
    2. I iterate list on scala.html file @for(d <-list){ 
    count++ or count+=1;// getting error
    }
    3. through this loop need to print number with questions
    like Sr.No  QuestionName Option..
          1         ABC         A..
          2         ZYX         D..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk28y.png)

Comment: Please do **NOT** add code as link to an image. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58340834/edit) and put the code snippet in as formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use zipWithIndex feature on scala collections (more information in scala documentation: [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/View$$ZipWithIndex.html));

Exaple use:

```
@for((value, index) <- list.zipWithIndex){

  @* Print value *@
  @value 

  @* Print index - first index will be 0 *@
  @index

  @* Print index + 1 *@
  @{index+1}

}
```